# Read response output buffer/stream with supertest/superagent on node.js server

Tags: node.js, zip, mocha.js, superagent, supertest

I am trying to write a test that checks whether an API route outputs a ZIP file with the correct contents.

I am using mocha and supertest for testing, and I would like to actually read the output stream/buffer, read the zip file contents and see if the contents are correct.

Any ideas how should I do it? When I try to read `res.body`, it's just an empty object.

```
  request(app)
    .get( "/api/v1/orders/download?id[]=1&id=2" )
    .set( "Authorization", authData )
    .expect( 200 )
    .expect( 'Content-Type', /application\/zip/ )
    .end( function (err, res) {
      if (err) return done( err );

      console.log( 'body:', res.body )

      // Write the temp HTML file to filesystem using utf-8 encoding
      var zip = new AdmZip( res.body );
      var zipEntries = zip.getEntries();

      console.log( 'zipentries:', zipEntries );

      zipEntries.forEach(function(zipEntry) {
        console.log(zipEntry.toString()); // outputs zip entries information
      });

      done();
    });
```

Answer (score 39):

Expanding on @Beau's answer, the following can be used to get any binary response content as a Buffer which you can examine further in `request.end()`:

```
function binaryParser(res, callback) {
    res.setEncoding('binary');
    res.data = '';
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        res.data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        callback(null, new Buffer(res.data, 'binary'));
    });
}

// example mocha test
it('my test', function(done) {
    request(app)
        .get('/path/to/image.png')
        .expect(200)
        .expect('Content-Type', 'image.png')
        .buffer()
        .parse(binaryParser)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) return done(err);

            // binary response data is in res.body as a buffer
            assert.ok(Buffer.isBuffer(res.body));
            console.log("res=", res.body);

            done();
        });
});
```

Comment: This works great, although I had to add `.buffer()` to the request.

Comment: With @Nate, from the [docs](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#parsing-response-bodies), "If response buffering is not enabled (.buffer(false)) then the response event will be emitted without waiting for the body parser to finish, so response.body won't be available".

Comment: @ZachB so `.buffer().parse(binaryParser)`?

Comment: @rcoup yes, say the docs, but it also seems to work fine without in a quick test. Longer responses might require it...?

Answer (score 5):

As descirbed in [Testing binary response with supertest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59576617/testing-binary-response-with-supertest) setting `.responseType('blob')` on the request will cause `req.body` to be a Buffer.

https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#binary

```
it('test', async () => {
  await request(app)
    .get('/api/some-zip')
    .responseType('blob')
    .expect(200)
    .expect('Content-Type', /application\/zip/)
    .expect(( res) => {
      const zipEntries = new AdmZip(res.body).getEntries().map(e => e.entryName);
      expect(zipEntries).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(['zipfile1.pdf', 'zipfile2.pdf']));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want to create your own parser for application/zip and use that to get at the actual response data; the JSON parser is [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/lib/node/parsers/json.js), for example. Once you've got that you can use it by passing it to request.parse; so your test would become:

```
request(app)
  .get( "/api/v1/orders/download?id[]=1&id=2" )
  .set( "Authorization", authData )
  .expect( 200 )
  .expect( 'Content-Type', /application\/zip/ )
  .parse( function (res, fn) {
    res.data = '';
    res.on( 'data', function (chunk) { res.data += chunk; } );
    res.on( 'end', function () {
      try {
        fn( null, new AdmZip( res.data ) );
      } catch ( err ) {
        fn( err );
      }
    });
  })
  .end( function (err, res) {
    if (err) return done( err );

    console.log( 'body:', res.body )

    // Write the temp HTML file to filesystem using utf-8 encoding
    var zipEntries = res.body.getEntries();

    console.log( 'zipentries:', zipEntries );

    zipEntries.forEach(function(zipEntry) {
      console.log(zipEntry.toString()); // outputs zip entries information
    });

    done();
  });
```

To find the answer to this I mostly relied on inspecting the superagent test suite. :)

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers didn't work for me. What I ended up doing was:

```
// parses response.body buffer into a data object
const parsePDF = response => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // code that parses response.body as buffer
    // and calls resolve(data); when done
    // or reject(err); on error
  })
};

const binaryParser = require('superagent-binary-parser');

// test snippet
request(app)
    .get('/some/api/returning/pdf')
    .expect(200)
    .expect('content-type', 'application/pdf')
    .parse(binaryParser)
    .buffer()
    .then(parsePDF)
    .then((pdf) => {
      chai.expect(pdf.pages.length).to.be.equal(5);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same case where I needed to write a test to check the contents of a zip file. This is how I did it.

```js
    it('test', async function () {
        let data = '';
        const res = await request(app)
            .get('/api/some-zip')
            .parse((res, callback) => {
                res.setEncoding('binary');
                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    data += chunk;
                });
                res.on('end', function () {
                    callback(null, Buffer.from(data, 'binary'));
                });
            })
        const zip = new AdmZip(res.body)
        const zipEntries = zip.getEntries();

        expect(zipEntries[0].name).to.equal('zipfile1.pdf');
        expect(zipEntries[1].name).to.equal('zipfile2.pdf');
    });
```

I used async/await syntax